# CSS: How can I force a display: table-cell box to have a fixed width of 50%?

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<div id="frontpage_boxes">
    <div id="frontpage_boxes_inner">
        <div id="fp_box1" class="fp_box">...</div>
        <div id="fp_box2" class="fp_box">...</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#frontpage_boxes {
    margin-bottom:60px;
    margin-top:1vw;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

#frontpage_boxes_inner {
    display:table-row;
}

.fp_box {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The problem is I need display table-cell for the boxes to have equal height. They also should have equal width. Everything works great as long as there is a lot of space. However if space gets smaller the first box just grows bigger than 50% which breaks the layout.

How can I force a box with display:table-cell to have a width of 50% ignoring possibly available space?

Comment: Your code should work. Share a working example reproducing the issue. Your `table-layout: fixed` must do the trick

Comment: You should consider using flexbox instead of a table layout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've done is correct, they're both using up 50% of their parent, you need the parent to be 100% of the page for them to both be 50% of the page.

**EDIT:**
So I added width:100% to the parent so it would take up the entire page.

See example below.

```css
#frontpage_boxes {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#frontpage_boxes_inner {
  display: table-row;
}

.fp_box {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="frontpage_boxes">
  <div id="frontpage_boxes_inner">
    <div id="fp_box1" class="fp_box">...</div>
    <div id="fp_box2" class="fp_box">...</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In other words, just add `width: 100%` to the element with `display: table`.

Comment: I've been looking for a while for a great all around solution to center an image inside of a div for many email clients. I finally decided to use `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` which was working great, but my desktop reader wasn't maintaining the aspect ratio of my cell. Adding `box-sizing: border-box` solved this issue.